# Codeigniter, Postgresql and keys insensitivity

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

I have one proble. I have my site based on Codeigniter framework, with postgresql database.
If i do this code:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where(array('name' => 'moscow'));
$this->db->get('Cities');
```

I have empty result.

but in my table i have city with field name = Moscow.

How i can to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Remove the `from` condition. `$this->db->get('Cities');` produces:

```
 SELECT * FROM cities
```

so no need of an extra `from` condition. Change your query to :

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where(array('name' => 'moscow'));
$this->db->get('Cities');
```

Comment: yes, now it's true, but also i see 0 results. Problem in keys sensitivity only

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  $this->db->select('id,name');
  $this->db->from('Cities');
  $this->db->where('name','moscow');

  $sql= $this->db->get();
  if($sql->num_rows()>0)
  {
      return $sql->result();
  }   
  else{

      return FALSE;
  }
```

Comment: Problem only witn keys sensitivity. How to solve it?

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: result is 0 records But if i do 'Moscos' on where, i get one record

Comment: change in where moscow to Moscow

Comment: yep, if i use 'Moscow' with upper M - i've 1 record

Comment: but i have see no solution here. Thi is no solution to write with first upper symbol.

Comment: data are case sensitive in DB. If you will not give exact value in where then how can you get records.